# xss payload "-confirm``-"

Tags: xss

I found ``` -confirm``- ``` this payload on xsstrike while scanning one of my websites. I want to know more about it.

[image: Scanning output]

Comment: OK. And your question is?

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Copy/paste and use the code formatting tool. At least constrain the picture to the relevant part that you want to show, not the whole desktop.

Comment: Also relevant: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Answer (score 0):

It's a payload for a sink inside a JavaScript string context. It might eg exploit the following vulnerable code:

```
<script>var x = "[user input]";// process x</script>
```

The payload uses `confirm` because some applications filter `alert`; using `` removes the need for `(` and `)` in the payload, and the biggest advantage is that subtraction (`-`) is used to add new statements (in place of eg `;`).

An alternative payload exploiting the same issue would eg be `";alert(1);x="`. But ``` "-confirm``-" ``` has the advantage that it leaves the rest of the code completely intact. It can eg be used in contexts such as this, where other generic payloads may fail:

```
<script>
x("[user input]");
function x(y) {
    alert(y);
}
</script>
```

If you weren't using subtraction in your payload, you would need to "fix" the code before and after your injection  (eg `");alert(1);//`. But that payload isn't generic anymore (it wouldn't work for the first example).

Comment: <script> tag is also filtered...Do you have any "-confirm``-" payloads for xss